# Highlighing individual data points with ggplot created from pipes

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-point

We have this simple data frame:

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("a","b"), each = 500),
                   time = 1:500,
                val = rnorm(1000, mean=1, sd = 0.3))
```

We have data for 2 individuals (`ID` == `a` and `b`). We want to subset the data for individual `b` and make a scatterplot of `val` vs `data_point` using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  filter(ID == "b")%>%
  mutate(data_point = c(1:500))%>%
  ggplot(.,)+
    geom_point(aes(x=data_point, y=val), size = 0.5)
```

[image]

Now say we want to make a single data point (say the very first data point/row) larger than the rest, and a different color. How can we do that from inside this pipe, without having to make an object outside of the pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two variables inside the pipe, one for the highlight color and the other for its size.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(ID == "b") %>%
  mutate(data_point = 1:500) %>%
  mutate(highlight = data_point == 1,
         size = 0.5 + 10*highlight) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = data_point, y = val)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = highlight, size = size), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

Another way, without creating those two variables is to apply the same logic to the aesthetics call in `geom_point`.

```
data %>%
  filter(ID == "b") %>%
  mutate(data_point = 1:500) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = data_point, y = val)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = data_point == 1, 
                 size = 0.5 + 10*(data_point == 1)), 
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

On both case the result is as follows.

[image]

## Edit

Thanks to @Allan Cameron for having noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365914/highlighing-individual-data-points-with-ggplot-created-from-pipes/63366181#comment112048462_63366181) that:

> You would only need a single new variable in the first version, then
> use scale_size

The result is almost the same, with a 0.5 difference in `size` for the highlighted point.

```
data %>%
  filter(ID == "b") %>%
  mutate(data_point = 1:500) %>%
  mutate(highlight = data_point == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = data_point, y = val)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = highlight, size = highlight), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.5, 10*highlight))
```

Comment: You would only need a single new variable in the first version, then use `scale_size`

Answer (score 0):

You could create another column within `mutate()` to handle point size. In this example, sizing_point is a vector starting with 5, followed by the number 0.5 repeating `nrow(.)-1` times, or 499 times in this case.

```
 #multiple columns can be defined in mutate() separated by a comma
 data %>% 
      filter(ID == "b") %>%
      mutate(sizing_point = c(5,rep(0.5,nrow(.)-1)), data_point = c(1:500))%>%
      ggplot(.,)+
      geom_point(aes(x=data_point, y=val, size= sizing_point)
```

You could highlight a different point of course. Let's say your wanted to highlight the 75th point. Here is one example of how to could specify the point size for that item.

```
  #repeats .05 74 times, followed by 5, then repeats 0.5 again to the end of the vector
  c(rep(0.5,74),5,rep(0.5,nrow(.)-75))
```

And to add color to the highlighted point:

```
data %>% 
  filter(ID == "b") %>%
  mutate(sizing_point = c(5,rep(0.5,nrow(.)-1)), data_point = c(1:500))%>%
  ggplot(.,)+ geom_point(aes(x=data_point, y=val, size= sizing_point, color=factor(sizing_point)))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```